# If $U \leq \mathbb{R}^4$, $\dim(U) =3$ and $\langle(0,0,0,1)\rangle \cap U = \{0\}$ then $U = \langle(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

> Suppose $U \leq \mathbb{R}^4$, $\operatorname{dim}(U)=3$ and $\langle(0,0,0,1)\rangle \cap U =  \{0\}$. Is it then true that $U = \langle(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)\rangle$?

I say yes. Here's my reasoning:
Put the three basis vectors of $U$ into RRE form. That is consider the matrix with the three basis vectors as rows. The only RRE form that doesn't contain $(0,0,0,1)$ is the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0 &0 & 0\\0&1&0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &1 &0\end{bmatrix}$. This proves the claim.

Is this correct?

Comment: Think about this question in one dimension lower: Does every plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which does not contain $(0,0,1)$ have to be the $xy$-plane?

Comment: Sorry! I made a typo in my question. Will edit!

Comment: Take the line $y=x$ then $(0,1)$ is not parralel to the line.. Does that mean that $(1,0)$ is paralel to the line?

Comment: Made an edit to my question!

Comment: @user I see your edit. My original comment still applies though. Does every plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which intersects the $z$-axis only at the origin have to be the $xy$-plane?

Comment: No! So where did my argument go wrong? Also just noticed that my edit made no difference what so ever , as subspaces are closed :D

Comment: @user I'll detail that a little more in a full answer.

Comment: Your title and actual question are not the same. If $U$ is a $3-$dimensional subspace in $\Bbb{R}^4$, then $U$ will be isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$, regardless of any other extra condition. But your question is about a specific subspace. So changing the title will be better.

Comment: @AnuragA I don't believe that isomorphisms are mentioned at any point in the title or question.

Comment: @Anonymous It was not (before the change), but then saying $U=\Bbb{R}^3$ is misleading in the strictest sense. Because technically speaking if you refer to $\Bbb{R}^3$ as the $xyz$ space then it is not even a subset of $\Bbb{R}^4$ let alone a subspace. So the understanding is that all $3$-dim subspaces in $\Bbb{R}^4$ are isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$ and that is why some may write $U=\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @AnuragA I see what mean, and yea I see why that's misleading. I suppose the question was all meant to be about strict equality, but $\mathbb{R}^3$ was used as a shorthand for $\text{span}\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$ when they are really only isomorphic as you said.

Comment: Yes! I thought it made the title easier to read. I do see that the title question is different from the question in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $U=\text{span}\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}$ which has dimension $3$ since $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}$ is clearly linearly independent. If $U$ were equal to $\text{span}\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$, then $U$ would have $(0,0,1,1)-(0,0,1,0)=(0,0,0,1)$ as an element and would therefore equal all of $\mathbb{R}^4$, which is impossible. Furthermore, $U$ does not contain a nonzero multiple of $(0,0,0,1)$ since that would also imply that $U=\mathbb{R}^4$ by similar reasoning.

The issue with your argument is that the RRE of the matrix whose rows are basis vectors may not be the matrix you listed. With the example I listed before, the RRE form of the matrix and will be

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

If, alternatively, you made the basis vectors the columns of the matrix and put it into RRE form, the reasoning would fail for a different reason. That is, the column space of a matrix is not always the same as the column space of the RRE form version of that matrix. The two column spaces will be $\textit{isomorphic}$ since they will have the same dimension, but they may not be $\textit{equal}$ as subsets of the ambient vector space. For a simple example of this phenomenon, take the matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

whose column space is the $y$ axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The RRE form of $A$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ whose column space is the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. Just one question: The echelon form of my matrix must be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1&a & b & c\\0 &1 & d & e \\ 0 &0&1&f\end{bmatrix}$, right?

Comment: @user Yes, and in fact, you will have $a=b=d=0$ if it is reduced. Also, I misread your question and assumed you used the basis vectors as the columns of your matrix instead of the rows, so I need to make an addition to my initial answer.

Comment: Ah so that's the issue with my answer! I assumed $c =e=f=0$ also!

Comment: @user Yup. Unlike with column space, the row space is preserved by elementary row operations, but that means the there are strong restrictions on what rows can be obtained from the elementary row operations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Problem solved!